# How to set values from each line of a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have this text file:

```
NJ01_27Ground
nj01stripclub
others...
```

Ok, now I want set their values instead of model name in this batch file I have just written:

```
Set /p "r=Model name? >> "
if exist "F:\Map 4 animation\%r%.obj" (echo %r%>>Loaded.txt) else (echo %r%>>Unloaded.txt)
test.bat>>test.bat
```

I mean for example this will be for the first line:

```
set r=NJ01_27Ground
if exist "F:\Map 4 animation\%r%.obj" (echo %r%>>Loaded.txt) else (echo %r%>>Unloaded.txt)
test.bat>>test.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

The batch code below creates a batch file with name `ExistenceCheck.bat`.

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "OutputBatch=ExistenceCheck.bat"
>"%OutputBatch%" echo @echo off
>>"%OutputBatch%" echo del Loaded.txt Unloaded.txt 2^>nul
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%I in ("InputTextFile.txt") do (
    >>"%OutputBatch%" echo if exist ^"F:\Map 4 animation\%%I.obj^" ^(echo %%I^>^>Loaded.txt^) else ^(echo %%I^>^>Unloaded.txt^)
)
endlocal
```

For each non blank/empty line in `InputTextFile.txt` one line is appended to output file `ExistenceCheck.bat`.

The file `ExistenceCheck.bat` contains finally for example:

```
@echo off
del Loaded.txt Unloaded.txt 2>nul
if exist "F:\Map 4 animation\NJ01_27Ground.obj" (echo NJ01_27Ground>>Loaded.txt) else (echo NJ01_27Ground>>Unloaded.txt)
if exist "F:\Map 4 animation\nj01stripclub.obj" (echo nj01stripclub>>Loaded.txt) else (echo nj01stripclub>>Unloaded.txt)
```

I hope, this batch file is what you finally want.

`Test.bat>>Test.bat` is definitely not a good idea. Executing a batch file which appends its output to itself at end being also processed by command processor can easily result either in a syntax error or a nearly endless running batch file.